# Set custom icon and text in ActionBar

Tags: android

I'm trying to set a custom icon and text in my ActionBar like WhatsApp does (Profile image and username).

```
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    BitmapDrawable actionBarBackground = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), chatPartner.getAvatar(this));
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    ab.setLogo(actionBarBackground);
    ab.setTitle(chatPartner.getUsername());
```

But the logo is not displayed, only the title.[image]

Comment: What you mean? I'm using the navigation drawer + ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing concepts. You are using the new [Toolbar](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) which does not have an icon. What Whatsapp uses is the old [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), which has an icon. That's why you don't see an icon, because the new Toolbar doesn't have one. You are probably targeting API 21 and using the AppCompat library, which takes care of providing a toolbar for you, even though in code you reference it using the ActionBar.

EDIT: Ok, if you have a very strong reason to use the old ActionBar with an icon, you can use version 19 of the support library

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
```

and target sdk 19

```
targetSdkVersion 19
```

Your code should work out of the box.

Comment: I am targeting API Level 11 and higher and AppCompat v7, so I should currently use the old ActionBar?

Comment: No, you're doing things *kind of* correctly. The latest Android design guidelines replace the old Actionbar with the new Toolbar, therefore your app, *as is*, is correct. Forcing the old Actionbar is wrong IMO. I said *kind of* because you're using a Toolbar, but referring to it in code as an Actionbar.

Comment: Where am I using a toolbar?

Comment: The AppCompat library is putting it there for you, because it's smart enough to know that even though you didn't request one, that was probably what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can tried following with custom actionbar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.slide_menu); //you can set here image
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(null);
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.signinheader));
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) activity
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);// custom layout
actionBartitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
actionBartitle.setText(getResources()
        .getString(R.string.my_london_trip));

getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

NOTE : You can set title as you want using `actionbarTitle.settext("TEXT")`

### actionbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/signinheader" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCartCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cart1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4.5dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/audio_guide_palyer_back"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

getSupportedActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [ToolBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) insted of the ActionBar that you are already using. Because ToolBars are easy to customize and manipulate. Here is a [link](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html) to a small tutorial that will help you to set the text and Image